# Reading MLDv2 queries using an IPv6 socket

Tags: sockets, ipv6, icmp, multicastsocket

I have [mrd6](https://github.com/hugosantos/mrd6) installed on my raspberry pi.  It registers with a local interface (tun0) and periodically transmits MLDv2 queries over it.

According to [[RFC3810](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3810)], MLDv2 message types are a subset of ICMPv6 messages, and are identified in IPv6 packets by a preceding Next Header value of 58 (0x3a).  They are sent with a link-local IPv6 Source Address, an IPv6 Hop Limit of 1, and an IPv6 Router Alert option [[RFC2711](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2711)] in a Hop-by-Hop Options header.

I can confirm that I'm seeing these packets periodically over tun0:

```
pi@machine:~ $ sudo tcpdump -i tun0 ip6 -vv -XX

01:22:52.125915 IP6 (flowlabel 0x71df6, hlim 1, next-header Options (0)
payload length: 36) 
fe80::69bf:be2d:e087:9921 > ip6-allnodes: HBH (rtalert: 0x0000) (padn)
[icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, multicast listener query v2 [max resp delay=10000]
[gaddr :: robustness=2 qqi=125]
            0x0000:  6007 1df6 0024 0001 fe80 0000 0000 0000  `....$..........
            0x0010:  69bf be2d e087 9921 ff02 0000 0000 0000  i..-...!........
            0x0020:  0000 0000 0000 0001 3a00 0502 0000 0100  ........:.......
            0x0030:  8200 b500 2710 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ....'...........
            0x0040:  0000 0000 0000 0000 027d 0000            .........}..
```

I have a socket set up in my application on tun0 as follows, since I expect these to be ICMP packets:

```
int fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMPV6); // ICMP

// ... bind this socket to tun0

  int interfaceIndex = // tun0 interface Index
  int mcastTTL = 10;
  int loopBack = 1;

  if (setsockopt(listener->socket,
                 IPPROTO_IPV6,
                 IPV6_MULTICAST_IF,
                 &interfaceIndex,
                 sizeof(interfaceIndex))
      < 0) {
    perror("setsockopt:: IPV6_MULTICAST_IF:: ");
  }

  if (setsockopt(listener->socket,
                 IPPROTO_IPV6,
                 IPV6_MULTICAST_LOOP,
                 &loopBack,
                 sizeof(loopBack))
      < 0) {
    perror("setsockopt:: IPV6_MULTICAST_LOOP:: ");
  }

  if (setsockopt(listener->socket,
                 IPPROTO_IPV6,
                 IPV6_MULTICAST_HOPS,
                 &mcastTTL,
                 sizeof(mcastTTL))
      < 0) {
    perror("setsockopt:: IPV6_MULTICAST_HOPS::  ");
  }

  struct ipv6_mreq mreq6 = {{{{0}}}};
  MEMCOPY(&mreq6.ipv6mr_multiaddr.s6_addr, sourceAddress, 16);
  mreq6.ipv6mr_interface = interfaceIndex;

  if (setsockopt(listener->socket,
                 IPPROTO_IPV6,
                 IPV6_JOIN_GROUP,
                 &mreq6,
                 sizeof(mreq6))
      < 0) {
    perror("setsockopt:: IPV6_JOIN_GROUP::  ");
  }
```

Setting up the socket this way, I can receive ICMP echo requests, replies to my own address, and multicasts sent using the link-local multicast address.  However, I don't see ***any*** MLDv2 queries.

Here's my receive loop:

```
  uint8_t received[1000] = { 0 };
  struct sockaddr_storage peerAddress = { 0 };
  socklen_t addressLength = sizeof(peerAddress);
  socklen_t addressLength = sizeof(peerAddress);

  int receivedLength = recvfrom(sockfd,
                                received,
                                sizeof(received),
                                0,
                                (struct sockaddr *)&peerAddress,
                                &addressLength);

  if (receivedLength > 0) {
    // Never get here for MLDv2 queries.
  }
```

Researching this a bit further, I discovered the IPV6_ROUTER_ALERT socket option, which the man page describes as follows:

```
IPV6_ROUTER_ALERT
Pass forwarded packets containing a router alert hop-by-hop option to this socket.
Only allowed for SOCK_RAW sockets.  The tapped packets are not forwarded by the
kernel, it is the user's responsibility to send them out again.  Argument is a
pointer to an integer.  A positive integer indicates a router alert option value
to intercept.  Packets carrying a router alert option with a value field
containing this integer will be delivered to the socket.  A negative integer
disables delivery of packets with router alert options to this socket.
```

So I figured I was missing this option, and tried setting it as follows.  [[RFC2710](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2710)] 0 means Multicast Listener Discovery message.

```
  int routerAlertOption = 0;

  if (setsockopt(listener->socket,
                 IPPROTO_IPV6,
                 IPV6_ROUTER_ALERT,
                 &routerAlertOption,
                 sizeof(routerAlertOption))
      < 0) {
    perror("setsockopt:: IPV6_ROUTER_ALERT::  ");
  }
```

However, this gives me the ENOPROTOOPT error (errno 92).  Some more Googling (http://www.atm.tut.fi/list-archive/usagi-users-2005/msg00317.html) led me to the fact that you can't set the IPV6_ROUTER_ALERT option with the IPPROTO_ICMPV6 protocol.  It needs a socket defined using the IPPROTO_RAW protocol.

However, defining my socket as:

```
int fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
```

means I'm not able to receive any ICMP packets in my recvfrom anymore.

---

TL;DR: How do I read MLDv2 queries using an IPv6 socket?

---

***edit (answer):***
It appears conventional implementations of Linux will drop MLDv2 packets when passing them to an ICMPV6 socket.  Why this is, I'm not sure.  (Could be because of the next-header option.)

I followed the accepted answer below and went with an approach of reading raw packets on the tun0 interface.  I followed the ping6_ll.c example here: http://www.pdbuchan.com/rawsock/rawsock.html.

It uses a socket with (SOCK_RAW, ETH_P_ALL).  You can also set some SOL_PACKET options to filter on specific multicast rules on your interface.

Comment: I am also working on MLDv2 and I am also not able to send mld report.

Comment: Is there any command in kernel which can tell whether mld query is received or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick look at RFCs things aren't looking good. Per [RFC4443 (ICMPv6) 2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4443#section-2.4):

> 2.4.  Message Processing Rules

> Implementations MUST observe the following rules when processing
> ICMPv6 messages (from [RFC-1122]):

> (b) If an ICMPv6 informational message of unknown type is received,
> it MUST be silently discarded.

According to MLDv2 spec it makes use of types 130, 143, perhaps something else (not seeing more diagrams in the RFC), while valid ICMPv6 types are 1, 2, 3, 4, 101, 107, 127, 128, 129, 200, 201, 255.

It looks like the implementation (kernel) must drop MLDv2 packets if they are to be passed to an ICMPv6 socket. Personally I don't see much sense in making MLDv2 look like ICMPv6 if conventional implementations will drop the packet anyways, but I didn't see anything that contradicts this claim.

You can surely go deeper and use a raw socket, especially given that your stack doesn't recognize MLDv2 (perhaps there's a kernel patch to fix that?). But you'll have to parse IP and ICMP headers on your own then.

Comment: Thank you! It wasn't too ideal but after a bit of dirty work I was finally able to read MLDv2 packets as I intended, just using raw sockets.  I followed the ping6_ll example here: http://www.pdbuchan.com/rawsock/rawsock.html

Note: My kernel is quite new, so unless I'm missing something, it sounds like default / conventional implementations of Linux drop MLDv2 packets when passing to an ICMPv6 socket -- I wish this was stated clearly somewhere.

Comment: @SuveshPratapa, unfortunately, Linux doesn't always follow the RFCs.